# I'm trying to figure out how many unique dog breeds are currently at the shelter

Tags: postgresql

More info:

At the animal rescue shelter where you volunteer, you've been tasked with figuring out how many unique dog breeds are currently at the shelter. You have access to a PostgreSQL database containing a Dogs table with the following columns:

id int NOT NULL,
nickname varchar,
breed varchar,
age int
Write a query that outputs the number of distinct dog breeds recorded in the database.

[execution time limit] 10 seconds (psql)

Below is my attempt:

CREATE TABLE Dogs

(

ID int (6) NOTNULL,

nickname VARCHAR(50) NOTNULL,

breed VARCHAR(50),

age int (2)

);

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT breed) FROM Dogs
```